# Oracle Developer 10g works on Oracle Dtabase 21c XE?

Tags: oracleforms, oraclereports, oracle21c

I want to connect my oracle database 21c xe with Oracle Developer 10g (forms/reports)?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide a [MRE] explaining what part of the problem is causing you issues; what you have attempted and what the errors were with those attempts?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any reference on the Internet (My Oracle Support included). The *closest* information I managed to find is about [Forms 10g on database 19c](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/oracle-form-10g-with-oracle-database-19c-1092).

Michael Ferrante (from Oracle) said:

> Forms 10.1.2 has been out of support for over 10 years, long before Database 19 was even a "thing". This is not a supported configuration that I would consider for any production environment. That said, some people have claimed to get things working. So, it may be technically possible, although I personally would not do it nor would I recommend it.
>
> If you choose to ignore my warning and recommendation, I will say that if you plan to do it ensure that you are at least running the latest patched version of Forms 10.1 (10.1.2.3 - patch ID 5983622) and have installed the latest/last DB 10.1.0.5 client patch (4505133) into this home. As always, create a backup of the home before attempting to apply any patches.
> Following this guidance should help to reduce the risk of having problems.

Therefore, as 21c (XE) is even newer than 19c, you might - or might not - make it work. There's no guarantee that it will.